# error reporting web service call deployment in code

Tags: c#, architecture

I've got couple of web service calls., I am calling this directly without any wrapper classes. Now i am implementing a third web service which reports the error happend during a main web service call to the server.This third webservice call may get extended to be called everytime a error happens in the future.

I am trying to deal with this scenario in the followng ways

1) create a wrapper class for main web service calls and calls the third/error handling webservice from that web service calls.

2) create a wrapper for error handling routines and move all the routines to that class., whcih includes call to error/third reporting webservice.

which one is better approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> 1) create a wrapper class for main web
>   service calls and calls the
>   third/error handling webservice from
>   that web service calls.

That sounds much better.

> 2) create a wrapper for error handling
>   routines and move all the routines to
>   that class., whcih includes call to
>   error/third reporting webservice.

Consolidating logging into a reusable object is the right way to go, but I wouldn't hard-code it to something like a web service.

What happens if the web services fail due to network issues - your logging call will fail also (if I understand your design).